# Unity Parsing APK error [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl1662909328.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to build and run the project in Unity these errors shows and don't build. How can I solve the problem? Help immediately,

-I tried reinstall JDK and SDK

-I tried other phones

-I tried to ask everywhere

Errors:
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/853v2.png]
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yshMb.png]

Comment: Please show your SDK location path.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!
I delete two videos(.mp4) in Plugins/Android/assets/,and assets size change to 5.7MB(original 13.4MB),now I can build APK with compression method=LZ4HC and install with no error.
so maybe the problem is that when unity build APK,the assets size has limit?